# Titanium Facebook module authorize not working

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, titanium

I am trying a facebook login with the Facebook module on IOS (Titanium SDK version 5.2.2GA). 
On the ios simulator all works fine, but on a real iphone/ipad the authorize() simply doesn't do anything. Event tapping on the "Login with facebook" button won't do anything.

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];
fb.initialize();
fb.authorize();
```

On ios simulator, once I call the authorize(), I am prompted to the facebook page that asks me to authorize the app I am using. But on the real device it's just stuck without doing nothing (and in the console there aren't errors).

same behavior on iphones from 5 to 6s plus and ios 9.0 / 9.3

any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a PR to fix this over here: [MOD-2242](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/pull/46)

The reason is that the default behavior FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative seems to fail silently if you attempt to use .authorize **with** the facebook app installed on your device.